# strange behavior of array declaration in perl

Tags: perl

Please have a look at bellow code.
File contain test.csv

```
aa,OPEN,TEMP1
bb,CLOSE,TEMP2
cc,OPEN,TEMP3
dd,TERMINATED,TEMP4
```

Code:

```
use Data::Dumper;
sub main {
    my $file = 'test.csv';  
    my @lines1;
    my @values;

    unless (open (INPUT, $file)) {
        print " files does not exist";
    }   
    while (my $line = <INPUT>) {                
         @values = split /\s*,\s*/, $line;    
         push  @lines1, \@values;   
    }   
    foreach my $rr(@lines1) {
        print  Dumper ($rr)."\n";
    }
    close INPUT;
}
main();
```

CODE RESULT:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'dd',
          'TERMINATED',
          'TEMP4
'
        ];

$VAR1 = [
          'dd',
          'TERMINATED',
          'TEMP4
'
        ];

$VAR1 = [
          'dd',
          'TERMINATED',
          'TEMP4
'
        ];

$VAR1 = [
          'dd',
          'TERMINATED',
          'TEMP4
'
        ];
```

Now when I run the code all I get is last line printed 4 times.
but I declare array `@values` inside while loop everything works fine.
Can someone please explain me this strange behaviour.?

Thanks

Comment: Define variables in smallest scope possible, `my @values = split /\s*,\s*/, $line;` as `@values` doesn't need to be visible outside `while` loop, and as a side effect you get rid of unwanted behavior.

Comment: is this side effect or bug or correct behavior..? what is it exactly? cause i am over writing rather than appending  values in array every time loop runs.
so i belive it is appneding the values and then next time it is overwritting it?
is this correct?

Comment: It is correct behavior, as you're always referring to same variable/(memory location) `@values` array => `print \@values, "\n";`

Comment: any suggestion what i should do/read to get good theoretical knowledge of perl, right now i am just referring to some tutorials on youtube to learn perl

Comment: Take a look at [info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/info) page. Book: http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-Perl.productCd-1118013840.html

Comment: Plenty of good Perl tutorials listed at http://perl-tutorial.org/. Just searching YouTube is almost certainly going to find stuff by people who only *think* they know Perl :-/

Comment: Try this: `perl -F, -MData::Dumper -lane"print Dumper \@F" test.csv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you only have a single `@values` array and each time round your loop, you just overwrite the values in that same array. So you end up with multiple references to the same array which contains the last set of values that you put into it.

One solution is to create a new `@values` array each time you go round the loop.

```
while (my $line = <INPUT>) {               
  my @values = split /\s*,\s*/, $line;   
  push  @lines1, \@values;  
}
```

Another alternative is to take a copy of the array and push that reference onto `@lines1`.

```
while (my $line = <INPUT>) {               
  my @values = split /\s*,\s*/, $line;   
  push  @lines1, [ @values ];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that when you declare `@values` at the begining it is the same array value. So you take a reference to the same array so each loop overwrites the previous declaration. However if you declare the array in the loop then at the wnd of each iteration the array falls out of scope amd no longer points to the value. Then during the next iteration, the array is redecared with a new value.